# How to update data at big query upon onUpdate event

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-bigquery

I'm importing data from firebase to big query which is working fine at onWrite event and used table.insert function.
Now I want to update data at big query against onUpdate event but table.update function is not available and not working.suggest some other way.
below is my code

```
exports.updatetobigquery = 
functions.database.ref('/mn_users/{userId}/').onUpdate(event => {
  const dataset = 
bigquery.dataset('KHUSHUApp');//functions.config().bigquery.datasetname);

  const table = 
dataset.table('mn_users');//functions.config().bigquery.tablename);
      console.log('Uppercasing', event.data.val());
  return table.update({
    'id': event.data.key,
    'name': event.data.val().name,
    'email': event.data.val().email
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Best way to handle this:

- BigQuery has the ability to UPDATE data, but BigQuery is an analytical database - not a database optimized for updates.
- So avoid updating data in BigQuery, if you have other means of achieving your goals.
- Instead of updates, send new rows to BigQuery - de-duplicate and merge latest values later when analyzing. This pattern is great when you need the ability to go back to each time the state changed, and analyze that.